# what should be the best way to move my django rest app to https

Tags: django, ssl, ssl-certificate, django-rest-framework

I am using https://github.com/teddziuba/django-sslserver as an https server for my django-rest app. it works fine if I test it on admin or in chrome's api client(when admin runs on chrome as well). But whenever I try to test it from firefox, I get the following exception:

```
    Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 51984)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 295, in _handle_request_noblock
    self.process_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 321, in process_request
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 334, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "/home/diwakar/virtualenvs/everybillapienv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 102, in __init__
    super(WSGIRequestHandler, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 649, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "/home/diwakar/virtualenvs/everybillapienv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 167, in handle
    self.raw_requestline = self.rfile.readline(65537)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 476, in readline
    data = self._sock.recv(self._rbufsize)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 341, in recv
    return self.read(buflen)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 260, in read
    return self._sslobj.read(len)
SSLError: [Errno 1] _ssl.c:1429: error:14094418:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:tlsv1 alert unknown ca
```

1. Should I use that csrf_exempt decorator to get rid of this exception ? my app only have a mobile client, it would never have an browser/javascript client for sure.
2. How strong is django-sslserver ? Can I use it on production ?
3. What should be the easiest way to redirect http traffic to https here, I've heard a combination of easy-userena and django-privatebeta does it. Any suggestions ?

Comment: "Django SSL Server is a SSL-enabled **development server** for the Django Framework." (Emphasis mine) This error doesn't have anything to do with csrf.

Comment: So what you meant is, it should be used for development purposes only and it shouldn't be used for production environment ?

Comment: Exactly. You should use a proper production server like nginx or Apache.